# How can I modify this MOV assembly instruction to write a hard coded value?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I have the following line of x86 assembly that I'm trying to

```
mov     byte ptr [esp+1F4h+var_4], bl
```

Encoded as

```
88 9C 24 F0 01 00 00
```

...which I would like to modify to write a hard coded byte rather than the bl register. ...but I'm having trouble reading x86 the op code table [here](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder.html) in order to modify this byte code.  Also, are the two trailing null bytes to delimit the byte code from the next instruction, or can they be overwritten (in case the new instruction is longer)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt just use an assembler ;)

> the two trailing null bytes to delimit the byte code from the next
>   instruction

Those are not delimiters, they are part of the offset which is stored as 32 bits. The new instruction should be the same length. It's hard to fit a longer one, but a shorter one can be padded with `NOP` instructions. Unfortunately the version with the constant is indeed longer:

```
C6 84 24 F0 01 00 00 42 mov byte [esp+0x1f0], 0x42
```

You can't fit this in there, you might have to mess with the following instructions too, in case you can shorten them to make room.

Comment: hmm.... Maybe I can use a value in another register instead of a hardcoded value.  9C, I guess, is bl.   Is there a listing of which bits to set for a different register?

Comment: Yes, _Table 2-2. 32-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte_  in the _Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual  Volume 2: Instruction Set Reference, A-Z_ or the [32-bit ModR/M Byte table in the web page you linked](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder.html#modrm_byte_32).

Comment: What does the third byte do? 0x24?

Comment: That's a SIB byte (see [next table in the web page](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder.html#sib_byte_32)). It encodes the `[esp]` part.

Comment: Another alternative would be to place the new `mov` someplace else in the binary where you've got some free space, and replace the old `mov` with a `jmp` that jumps to the new `mov` (and then there'd be another `jmp` after the new `mov` that jumps back to where you came from). The `jmp` instruction can be encoded in 2 or 5 bytes, depending on whether it's a short jump or a near jump. Instead of two `jmp`s you could also use `call` and `ret`.